# What is the current drawn by a faulty appliance?

Tags: electrical

Is the current drawn by a faulty appliance greater than the rated value or is zero?

Comment: It depends on the fault. There is not enough information here. Short-circuit faults cause appliances to draw more current. Open-circuit faults cause appliances to draw less current.

Comment: It is whatever it wants to be.

Comment: what do you mean by `faulty`?

Answer (score 1):

An important fact that many inexperienced engineers forget, is that the term "faulty" only tells you what the behaviour of the device *isn't* - i.e the behaviour isn't *correct*.

**The term "faulty" does *not* tell you what the behaviour actually *is*.**

A faulty device can have literally *any* (physically possible) behaviour. So in addition to your two given options:

> greater than the rated value or [...] zero

... the current drawn could also be *less than* the rated value, but not zero, or fluctuating in any possible pattern / frequency or any other (physically possible) behaviour.

In summary, as I explained, the current drawn (or any other measurement of its behaviour) could be *any* physically possible result. It is not as simple as (in this example of current draw) just a choice between too much or zero.